# move_uploaded_file not working after preview page

Tags: php

I'm submitting a form to a preview page(form) and then a final submit.  I'm having trouble getting move_uploaded_file to work.  How do i solve this?   when i check the directory there is no file there.

preview page

```
      $tmpname = $_FILES['titleimage']['tmp_name'];
            $imagefile = $_FILES['titleimage']['name'];
          $filename = basename($imagefile);
           $imagename = dirname(__FILE__).'/avatar/'.$filename; 

            echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='submitpreview' action='/upload' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden'  name='image' value='$tmpname' readonly />
    <input type='hidden'  name='imagedir' value='$imagename' readonly />";
                        //other code
                echo "<div id='preview-submit-button'><a>Submit</a></div>
                </form>";
```

upload page

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
$directory = $_POST['imagedir'];

move_uploaded_file($image,$directory);
```

Comment: What you mean by "I'm having trouble getting move_uploaded_file to work" ?

Comment: The file should be uploaded to the directory but there is no file there after i submit the form.

Comment: After first submit, file is removed.More exactly it's removed when first request is complete.That's by design.

Comment: thats what i thought, is it possible to save the temporary file and delete? is so how? cookie?

Comment: Simply copy it anywhere you want from where you can move/delete it later

Comment: thanks, whats the php function to delete?

Comment: follow @lorenzo-s answer

Comment: You're directly using user-supplied data to specify paths AND filenames in the move function... you're allow malicious users to scribble on any file on your server they want to. enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the temporary file `$_FILES['titleimage']['tmp_name']` is still there after you submit the second form? Remember, it's a temporary file. I'm afraid it *lives* only for the time the first form is submitted (just until request is processed).

So, you should:

1. As soon as possible (that means, in the page that receive the first form, your preview page in fact) you save the temporary file in a folder of yours using **[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)**.
2. If the user **confirms** the preview, you move the file from the directory where you saved it in step *1* to its *definitive* folder, using the **[`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)** function.
3. If user **does not confirm** the preview, you delete it using **[`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)** function.

---

Additionaly, as **Marc B** pointed out, you should have a look to the security of your *preview-save* logic. Passing paths and filenames in hidden form field is a very good way to help hackers break your system. Have a look at **[PHP Sessions](http://it.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)** (maybe you already know), and consider moving that paths from the public form to a session variable.

Comment: thanks, what if there a duplicate filename in the temporary folder or definitive folder?  Is there a way to add a unique identifier for the file?

Comment: I'm using a function that checks if a file with that name exists already, and returns the same filename if not, or a suffixed non-existing filename is yes. Example, if *a.png* exists, it returns *a_2.png*, else it return *a.png*. Try to make your own. If you have dubts about how to do it, ask another question here, it's off-topic now.