# Form data and image preview after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I use wordpress cms and I need help with a custom made form. It allow users to post from front-end. There are a couple of fields and a image upload field. It is a two part form where the first part is where he submits data and second step where he gets a preview of data he just submitted. Please remember that **this happens after the submit**.

**FORM CODE :**

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $this_page  =   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $page       =   $_POST['page'];
    if ( $page == NULL ) { ?> 

<form method="post" action="">

<div>LOCATION : <input type="text" name="location"/></div>

<div>DESCRIPTION : <textarea id="details" cols="80" rows="10 maxlength="600" name="details" rows="20"></textarea></div>

<div>UPLOAD IMAGE : <input type="file" name="loc-image" id="loc-image" tabindex="25" /></div>


<input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post_action" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PROCEED"/>
</form>

<?php 
} else if ( $page == 1 ) { ?> 

<?php 
$location=$_POST['location'];
$description=$_POST['details'];
$photo=$_POST['loc-image'];

echo 'Location : ' . $location . '</br>';
echo 'Details  : ' . $description . '</br>'; 
echo 'Image    : ' . $photo . '</br></br>';
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

ISSUE : In the last step, my current code is able to display all submitted data along with the image name, but NOT the image. I would like to **display the image** at this point. Basically, I need the last step to be sort of a preview-page.

Code given below processes the form and I would like to pull your attention particularly to the specific part of the code which helps insert attachments, as it may help devise a solution.

**FORM PROCESSOR :**

```
   if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] &&  $_POST['action'] == "post_action") {

                //some error checking done here

                //set vars
                $location       =  $_POST['location'];
                $description =  $_POST['details'];


                if (empty($error)) {   
                $new_post = array(   //insert form inputs, set var and define array
                'post_title'    =>  $location, 
                'post_content'  =>  $description,
                'post_status'   =>  'draft', 
                'post_type' =>  'post',  
                // assigning tags and categoris is no issue
                );

                $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

                                        //attachment helper function    
                                        function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

                                            if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ return __return_false(); 
                                            } 
                                            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                                            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                                            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

                                            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

                                            //set post thumbnail
                                            if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
                                            return $attach_id;
                                            }


                                        //INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
                                        if ($_FILES) {
                                        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                                        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
                                        // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
                                        // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
                                        }
                                        } // end of attachment statement
    }
    }
```

Footnote : Other than the issue the code has been heavily customized and works well on my wp-install. So, please ignore secondary factors in the code eg. validations, security etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I needed a preview after the form submit the solution was relatively easier than I thought, especially when I already had the attachment id `$newupload` assigned and declared in the code. So I completely went the wordpress route and used the code below to call the image, which works like charm.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $newupload,'medium' ); ?>
```

Follow the link to read more about [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image). Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

IF i am right that you didn't save image in temp folder so first save  into temp folder and display image on preview page using image path like [Drive name]:/[Folder name] /[img_path]

After submission form, remove image from Temp Folder and saved into your orginal folder.

Comment: I think this link may be help you...     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899090/move-uploaded-file-not-working-after-preview-page

Comment: thanks for the effor, I have it sorted now. taken a wordpress route.