# warning due to unlink file function - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a form to post in the frontend of my wordpress site. I allow image upload and have the following code to process the image.

**ISSUE** : Several times during the test on live server, I have been getting this warning while trying to upload images bigger than the specified file size (1 MB).

> Warning: unlink(/tmp/phpKX8Ydz) [function.unlink]: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home2/base/public_html/wp-content/themes/construct/multiparts/validation/validate_third_part.php
>   on line 54

Given below is the code in the specific line 54 outlined above.

```
unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
```

Not sure if it matters at all but here are couple of pointers that may help determine the issue faster if known.

1. It is a simple [multi-part form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222295/form-data-and-image-preview-after-form-submit) making use of hidden inputs to carry data forward.
2. I am testing it online on a LIVE server with debug mode set to off.
3. PHP Version 5.3.27. Hosted on Hostgator.
4. Except this warning glitch, everything else still works great.

**VALIDATION CODE :** mostly [taken from this source](http://voodoopress.com/posting-from-the-front-end-form-validation-reader-submission/).

```
//some minor form validations
    if (isset($_POST['submit-3'])) {
            $error = "";

     //checking other stuffs   

    // image validation starts
    if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {

    //Check if the $_FILES is set and if the size is > 0 (if =0 it's empty)
    if(isset($_FILES[$file]) && ($_FILES[$file]['size'] > 0)) {

    $tmpName = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmpName);

    if ($_FILES[$file]["size"] >= 1000000) {    
    $error .= 'Image file is too large. Image size must be within 1MB only.!<br />';
    unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
                        }

        // Get the type of the uploaded file. This is returned as "type/extension"
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES[$file]['name']));
        $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        // Set an array containing a list of acceptable formats
        $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

        // If the uploaded file is the right format
        if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {

        } else { // wrong file type
        $error .= "Accepted image formats only JPG, JPEG, GIF, or PNG files only. <br />";
        }

        } else {
        $error .= "Please add an image<br />";
        }
        } // end for each
        } // end if
}
```

**ATTACHMENT CODE :**

```
//attachment helper function    
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ return __return_false(); 
    } 

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

//set post thumbnail
if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
return $attach_id;
}

//imsert image
if ($_FILES) {
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
$newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
// $newupload returns the attachment id of the file
    }
} // end of attachment statement
```

Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know if a file exceeds PHP's limit it won't get written to /tmp - so your unlink() will always fail on big files.

Put the @ symbol before unlink (to suppress PHP's error messages - you have your own error notifications anyway) or do a file_exists() test before unlink()ing.

Comment: something like this.. -  `if(file_exists($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'])) { @unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']); }`

Comment: seems to work, but please correct me if the code is wrong. thanks.